# Drawing with GDI+ under IIS

Tags: iis-7, windows-services, service, gdi+

I'm running a web application under IIS that we draw graphs with that are sent to the clients.  We were previously running under iis6, while migrating to 2008 ( iis7 ) we have encountered some very weird issues with the graphing.  I stumbled across the msdn docs for GDI+ stating that "GDI+ functions and classes are not supported for use within a Windows service."  I suspect that my issues are probably related to further isolation of services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx

My question is how the heck are we supposed to draw graphics?  Raw GDI? OpenGL - but doesn't that still require a DC?

Answer (score 0):

I had asked a similar question:

[Why not use GDI+ from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562699/why-not-use-gdi-from-asp-net)

I ended up switching to the LeadTools libraries.

Of course, you can choose any library that is not device dependent.  GDI+ is depending on a device context which gives it a physical device to base it's graphics on.  However, when running as a service, the graphics adapter is probably not available for use as it would be in a desktop environment.

You could also write your own graphics routines which draw to a bitmap. A bitmap is simply raw memory arranged in a certain format.

Comment: I'll look into the leadtools libraries.  Really I guess what I need is some library to accomplish graphics drawing in a device independent manner.

Comment: We have an old version of their libraries - so this may have changed since the version we have.  I threw the dll into dependency walker & it is very dependent on GDI.

Comment: Try version 15+.  Also depends on what you are doing with their libraries.  There is the capability of interop between GDI+ and Leadtools.  What I did was to make an out-of-process server (just spawned a separate .exe that used Leadtools to do the graphics) then read the resulting jpeg file from within the asp.net application.

Comment: LeadTools was much faster (don't know exact percentage) than GDI+ at the image processing routines I was running.  So that may be a plus too.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on your particular situation given the details; but why not perform your graphics rendering with a simple asp.net application?  You can use the System.Drawing namespace which wraps GDI+

If you need just barebones functionality for rendering graphics and delivering to clients over HTTP, you can also use an HTTPHandler

Comment: Our drawing is done in native C++ libraries.  And as you pointed out Sysem.Drawing uses GDI+ under the hood - against the MSDN recommendations.