# Remap arbitrary grey scale colors in SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, image-processing, skiasharp

I am building a program to generate heat maps.  I am leveraging code written for GDI+, but for [various](https://photosauce.net/blog/post/5-reasons-you-should-stop-using-systemdrawing-from-aspnet) [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562699/why-not-use-gdi-from-asp-net) I've decided to move it to [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) instead.

I currently have an image tile in grey scale, where white represents maximum value and pure black is transparent.  In GDI+ / C# I could use `ColorMap` and `SetRemapTable` to quickly.  I've looked at ColorFilter, but that seams to use a matrix transform, vs. my somewhat arbitrary remapping.

Does SkiaSharp have anything analogous to this?  Or should I manually iterate over each pixel and recolor it?

Original code using GDI+:

```
ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
ColorMap[] remapTable = new ColorMap[256];
Color[] scale = IncandescentHeatScale();

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    remapTable[i] = new ColorMap()
    {
        OldColor = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i),
        NewColor = scale[i]
    };
}

imageAttributes.SetRemapTable(remapTable);

var outTile = new Bitmap(TileSize, TileSize);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(outTile))
{
    g.DrawImage(tile, new Rectangle(0, 0, TileSize, TileSize), padding, padding, TileSize, TileSize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);
}
```

Related functions, for reference:

```
static Color[] GetHeatScale(float[] points, Color[] colors)
{
    var bm = new Bitmap(256, 1);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
    {
        LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(256, 0), colors[0], colors[colors.Length - 1]);
        var cb = new ColorBlend();
        cb.Colors = colors;
        cb.Positions = points;
        brush.InterpolationColors = cb;
        g.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 256, 1);
    }
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(x => bm.GetPixel(x, 0)).ToArray();
}


static Color[] IncandescentHeatScale()
{
    float[] points = new float[] { 0.0f, 0.333f, 0.6666f, 1f };
    Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.Black, Color.DarkRed, Color.Yellow, Color.White };
    return GetHeatScale(points, colors);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Skia/SkiaSharp will let you transform colors.  Aside from using a Matrix transform, you can use color remap tables.

Create an SKColorFilter using `SKColorFilter.CreateTable(alphaRemapTable, redRemapTable, blueRemapTable, greeenRemapTable)`

These tables are byte arrays, 256 elements long.  Remapping works such that the component of the starting colour is used as the index to look up the value it should remap to, eg. 10 red transforms to the value in the red array at index 10.

Passing null into any of the arguments will leave that color component unchanged.

Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/color-filters

Comment: Okay - I think I went to the `CreateTable` doc page, which is void of salient details.  Sounds like in my scenario, I would take my 1x256 gradient and just create 3 arrays (R,G, B) where the value of r[i] is just the sample of the red channel for each index.  Easy peasy!

Comment: Yeah the docs leave plenty to be desired.  I stumbled upon this question a couple of days ago while I was trying to figure it out myself.  You might even need to take multiple passes with different tables. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution for all of you who actually just want to copy some code quickly. I know the question is two years old, but it's the only thing you can find on the subject at all. This code transforms a SKBitmap into a colored Bitmap.

```
public Bitmap Colorize(SKBitmap bitmap, SKImageInfo info)
    {
        using (SKSurface surface = SKSurface.Create(info))
        {
            SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

            using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
            {
                paint.ColorFilter = CreatePaletteIndex_skia(255);

                canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, info.Rect, paint);
            }

            using (SKImage image = surface.Snapshot())
            using (SKData data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100))
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data.ToArray()))
            {
                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(memoryStream, false);
                return bm;
            }

        }
     }

    private static SKColorFilter CreatePaletteIndex_skia(byte Alpha)
    {
        byte[] R = new byte[256];
        byte[] G = new byte[256];
        byte[] B = new byte[256];
        byte[] A = new byte[256];

        string dirExe = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        string colorImg = "ColorPalette.png";
        string pathColorPalette = dirExe + "Content\\" + colorImg;

        Bitmap Palette = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(pathColorPalette);
        // Loop through each pixel and create a new color mapping
        for (int X = 0; X <= 255; X++)
        {
            R[X] = Palette.GetPixel(X, 0).R;
            G[X] = Palette.GetPixel(X, 0).G;
            B[X] = Palette.GetPixel(X, 0).B;
            A[X] = Alpha;
        }

        SKColorFilter colorFilter = SKColorFilter.CreateTable(A, R, G, B);

        return colorFilter;
    }
```

You just put a picture([gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5kEH.png)) of a gradient 256 pixels wide into a folder of your project and link it via the variable pathColorPalette.

The code is based on this project on how to do this without skia: http://dylanvester.com/2015/10/creating-heat-maps-with-net-20-c-sharp/

Comment: This is terrible, but at least SOMETHING exists for this.